# Interpreting a coefficient for a matched/weighted data set for non-linear outcomes

Tags: regression, causality, propensity-scores, matching, marginal-effect

Prior research has demonstrated that the interpretation of a regression coefficient no longer represents the marginal effect once non-linear term transformations (logs, interactions, etc.) are introduced or when a non-linear outcome is being modeled. Under a regression adjustment setting, one can estimate the marginal effect under such settings using model predictions, with common approaches being taking the average effect of all estimated marginal effects for each unit (AME) or for estimating the marginal effect of the most "average" case (MEM).

Within the context of regression adjustment, this makes sense to me. However, when there are no covariates specified in the model (such as with a matched or IPW data set), is the estimation of marginal effects still appropriate? How is the marginal effect different than an estimated coefficient when the only coefficient in the model is the coefficient for treatment itself? (Assume I am speaking of a situation with a non-linear outcome).

Conceptually, I admit that I am a bit foggy on this application of marginal effects to matched/IPW data sets, so apologies if my question seems unfocused. I understand that regression coefficients on their own fail to represent the marginal effect in most cases. Second, marginal effects can still be estimated, but the regression coefficient fails to represent the marginal effect. Third, model predictions are used to generate a marginal effect. I have only personally seen marginal effects implemented with regression adjustment, but I am curious if one could estimate the marginal effect in the same way with a matched/IPW data set.